# Is there any other free flow diagram maker package than Graphite for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, diagram, graphite, flow-diagram

I want to add a flow diagram board to my Flutter application that users can add/remove blocks by drag and drop, edit block shapes or add `onPressed()` functionality to them, connecting the blocks together and also run something by taping on them. I found the [Graphite](https://pub.dev/packages/graphite) package but still interested o know is there any other free options available?